# ¿Cómo añadir hijos a un modelo en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relacion de muchos a muchos de dos tablas en mysql, algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado sus respectivos modelos con sus relaciones y me funcionan las consultas correctamente.

cuando hago esta consulta

```
$companies = Company::find($id);
return $this->sendResponse($companies, 'compania encontrada correctamente');
```

me devuelve un gson de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando consulto la tabla actividades:

```
$actividades = Company::find(1)->actividadesComerciales()->orderBy('id')->get();
```

me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber si se puede añadir las actividades dentro de la compania, algo asi

```
        {
            "success": true,
            "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "ruc": "20202020202",
            "business_name": "MYCOMPANIA",
            "address": "San juan bautista N° 234",
            "phone": "987567967",
            "item": "consultoria",
            "user_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-02-06 14:08:58",
            "updated_at": "2020-02-06 14:08:58",
            "business_type": "Empresa Individual de Resp. Ltda",
            "company_condition": 1,
            "start_activities_date": "2020-02-06",
            "legal_address": "Av. El Sol N° 850 Barrio Porteño",
            "distrito_id": 1251
            "actividades": [
                {
                "id": 1,
                "actividad": "Construcción Edificios Completos",
                "pivot": {
                "company_id": 1,
                "actividad_id": 1
                }
                },
                {
                "id": 2,
                "actividad": "Act. de Asesoramiento Empresarial",
                "pivot": {
                "company_id": 1,
                "actividad_id": 2
                }
                }
                ],
            },
            "message": "actividades encontradas correctamente"
        }
```

este es mi funcion sendResponse:

```
public function sendResponse($result, $message)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => $result,
            'message' => $message,
        ];


        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Muestra como definiste las relaciones en los modelos

Answer (score 0):

La solucion era sencilla, tenia que añadir las actividades dentro de el cada objeto de la compania de esta forma:

```
$company = Company::find($id);
$actividades = Company::find($id)->actividadesComerciales()->orderBy('id')->get();
$company['actividades'] = $actividades;
return $this->sendResponse($company, 'compania encontrada correctamente');
```

así me devuelve la data de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, si tienes bien tus modelos de Eloquent con `$this->hasMany` & `$this->belongsTo` en tu consulta podrías usar el metodo with para indicarle a la consulta que quieres la info con las relaciones que tenga tu modelo, que en este caso serían `Company->company_has_activities<-comercial_activities`. Tu query con Eloquent quedaría de esta manera:

```
$company = Company::find($id)->with('company_has_activities', 'company_has_activities.comercial_activities');
        // Ahora en tu object tendrías la `key` company_has_activities y dentro de esta la relacion con `comercial_activities`

    // Ojo este es un ejemplo
    // Suponiendo que tienes más de una actividad comercial relacionada a la company
    // con un ciclo for o foreach podrias iterar sobre los elementos y sacar los datos que estan mas al fondo que serian los de comercial_activities
    $company['company_has_activities'];
    $company['company_has_activities'][0]['comercial_activities'];
```

Yo aquí recomendaria usar un Resource de Laravel para mapear tu salida ( `php artisan make:resource Company`) y en el codigo de Resource hacer el mapeo de la salida =>

```
class Company extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $activities = [];
        foreach ($this->company_has_activities as $item ) {
$activities[] = $item['comercial_activities'];
}
        return [
          "id" => $this->id,
          "ruc" => $this->ruc,
          "business_name" => $this->business_name,
          "actividades" => $activities
        ];
    }
}
```

Ese es solo un ejemplo por eso no coloque todos los campos, pero ya en tu controller tendrías algo como esto:

```
$response = [
        'success' => true,
        'data'    => Company::collection($result),
        'message' => $message,
    ];


    return response()->json($response, 200);
```

Laravel Resources: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources
Laravel Eloquent Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yo revisaría de nuevo pues la imagen muestra una relación de muchos a muchos que es distinto a lo que propones

Answer (score -2):

Si se puede, solo tienes que usar la funcion "with" de eloquent.

No lo probé, pero tendría que ser algo así:

```
$companies = Company::find($id)->with('actividadesComerciales');
return $this->sendResponse($companies, 'compania encontrada correctamente');
```

Comment: Una explicación a tu código no caería mal

Comment: Es el codigo que dejo en la consulta, solo le aumente la funcion with, enserio requiere una explicacion?

Comment: Claro, considera que lo que es simple y obvio para ti no puede serlo para otros

Comment: Esta respuesta no solo carece de una explicación, además es incorrecta.